# Line plot in R, plot does not make sense

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset called "rainfall", the top few lines are

```
  Year    Month      Date cuftsec         lsec log10lsec
1 1997  January 1/15/1997  57.100 3.360907e-02 -1.473544
2 1997 February 2/15/1997  13.800 8.122686e-03 -2.090300
3 1997    March 3/15/1997   5.100 3.001866e-03 -2.522609
4 1997    April 4/15/1997   2.210 1.300812e-03 -2.885786
5 1997      May 5/15/1997   0.469 2.760590e-04 -3.558998
6 1997     June 6/15/1997   0.000 5.886000e-09 -8.230180
```

I would like to get a line plot of Date and log10lsec. When I try

```
with(rainfall, plot(x = Date, y = log10lsec, type = "l"))
```

I get a plot with points (as if type = "l" were not there).

If I set up another plot and then add a line, e.g. with

```
with(rainfall, plot(x = Date, y = log10lsec))
with(rainfall, lines(x = Date, y = log10lsec))
```

I get a preposterous line plot that connects points in seemingly random order.

dput(head(rainfall)) yields:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L
), Month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L), .Label = c("April", 
"August", "December", "February", "January", "July", "June", 
"March", "May", "November", "October", "September"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(1L, 49L, 61L, 73L, 85L, 97L), .Label = c("1/15/1997", 
    "1/15/1998", "1/15/1999", "1/15/2000", "1/15/2001", "1/15/2002", 
    "1/15/2003", "1/15/2004", "1/15/2005", "1/15/2006", "1/15/2007", 
    "1/15/2008", "10/15/1997", "10/15/1998", "10/15/1999", "10/15/2000", 
    "10/15/2001", "10/15/2002", "10/15/2003", "10/15/2004", "10/15/2005", 
    "10/15/2006", "10/15/2007", "10/15/2008", "11/15/1997", "11/15/1998", 
    "11/15/1999", "11/15/2000", "11/15/2001", "11/15/2002", "11/15/2003", 
    "11/15/2004", "11/15/2005", "11/15/2006", "11/15/2007", "11/15/2008", 
    "12/15/1997", "12/15/1998", "12/15/1999", "12/15/2000", "12/15/2001", 
    "12/15/2002", "12/15/2003", "12/15/2004", "12/15/2005", "12/15/2006", 
    "12/15/2007", "12/15/2008", "2/15/1997", "2/15/1998", "2/15/1999", 
    "2/15/2000", "2/15/2001", "2/15/2002", "2/15/2003", "2/15/2004", 
    "2/15/2005", "2/15/2006", "2/15/2007", "2/15/2008", "3/15/1997", 
    "3/15/1998", "3/15/1999", "3/15/2000", "3/15/2001", "3/15/2002", 
    "3/15/2003", "3/15/2004", "3/15/2005", "3/15/2006", "3/15/2007", 
    "3/15/2008", "4/15/1997", "4/15/1998", "4/15/1999", "4/15/2000", 
    "4/15/2001", "4/15/2002", "4/15/2003", "4/15/2004", "4/15/2005", 
    "4/15/2006", "4/15/2007", "4/15/2008", "5/15/1997", "5/15/1998", 
    "5/15/1999", "5/15/2000", "5/15/2001", "5/15/2002", "5/15/2003", 
    "5/15/2004", "5/15/2005", "5/15/2006", "5/15/2007", "5/15/2008", 
    "6/15/1997", "6/15/1998", "6/15/1999", "6/15/2000", "6/15/2001", 
    "6/15/2002", "6/15/2003", "6/15/2004", "6/15/2005", "6/15/2006", 
    "6/15/2007", "6/15/2008", "7/15/1997", "7/15/1998", "7/15/1999", 
    "7/15/2000", "7/15/2001", "7/15/2002", "7/15/2003", "7/15/2004", 
    "7/15/2005", "7/15/2006", "7/15/2007", "7/15/2008", "8/15/1997", 
    "8/15/1998", "8/15/1999", "8/15/2000", "8/15/2001", "8/15/2002", 
    "8/15/2003", "8/15/2004", "8/15/2005", "8/15/2006", "8/15/2007", 
    "8/15/2008", "9/15/1997", "9/15/1998", "9/15/1999", "9/15/2000", 
    "9/15/2001", "9/15/2002", "9/15/2003", "9/15/2004", "9/15/2005", 
    "9/15/2006", "9/15/2007", "9/15/2008"), class = "factor"), 
    cuftsec = c(57.1, 13.8, 5.1, 2.21, 0.469, 0), lsec = c(0.033609066, 
    0.008122686, 0.003001866, 0.001300812, 0.000276059, 5.886e-09
    ), log10lsec = c(-1.473543558, -2.090300341, -2.522608715, 
    -2.885785503, -3.55899764, -8.230179742)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Month", "Date", "cuftsec", "lsec", "log10lsec"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

TIA

Comment: what is the class of `Date`? is it a factor?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. We have no idea what `set up another plot` means.

Comment: You could make your example reproducible by posting the output of `dput(rainfall)`.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I edited my question to show that

Comment: @PeterFlom we really need the exact data that causes the problem. The two calls look alike, and I can see no obvious explanation other than that the data is the problem.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I added the results of `dput(rainfall)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is exactly that `Date` is a factor.  This seems to work:

```
with(dat,plot(as.Date(Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"),log10lsec,type="l"))
```

or if you want to transform the date permanently,

```
dat <- transform(dat,Date=as.Date(Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"))
with(dat,plot(log10lsec~Date,type="l"))
```